# Lookup in Spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using Spark 1.6 and I would like to know how to implement in lookup in the dataframes.

I have two dataframes employee & department.

- Employee Dataframe

  ```
  -------------------
  Emp Id | Emp Name
  ------------------
  1 | john
  2 | David
  ```
- Department Dataframe

  ```
  --------------------
  Dept Id | Dept Name | Emp Id
  -----------------------------
  1 | Admin | 1
  2 | HR | 2
  ```

I would like to lookup emp id from the employee table to the department table and get the dept name. So, the resultset would be

```
Emp Id | Dept Name
-------------------
1 | Admin
2 | HR
```

How do I implement this look up UDF feature in SPARK. I don't want to use JOIN on both the dataframes.

Comment: what you need  is "joining" the two dataframes... if one is very small, use a broadcast-join.

Comment: Do you have any code examples what you have so far?

Comment: This is what a `join` is mean to do. What are the reasons to try to implement this by some other means?

Comment: I have already implemented using join. But I want to explore using the look up concept as well (jus to learn and see the difference in implementation and performance). Does any one know?

Comment: You could convert your dataFrame to a `PairRDD` (e.g.. a `RDD[(Int,String)])` whichs provides a `lookup` method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, joining the dataframes is the way to go.

You can use a lookup, but I think there is no "distributed" solution, i.e. you have to collect the lookup-table into driver memory. Also note that this approach assumes that EmpID is unique:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._
import scala.collection.Map

val emp = Seq((1,"John"),(2,"David"))
val deps = Seq((1,"Admin",1),(2,"HR",2))

val empRdd = sc.parallelize(emp)
val depsDF = sc.parallelize(deps).toDF("DepID","Name","EmpID")


val lookupMap = empRdd.collectAsMap()
def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Int,String]) = udf((empID:Int) => lookupMap.get(empID))

val combinedDF = depsDF
  .withColumn("empNames",lookup(lookupMap)($"EmpID"))
```

My initial thought was to pass the `empRdd` to the UDF and use the `lookup` method defined on `PairRDD`, but this does of course not work because you cannot have spark actions (i.e. `lookup`) within transformations (ie. the UDF).

EDIT:

If your empDf has multiple columns (e.g. Name,Age), you can use this

```
val empRdd = empDf.rdd.map{row =>
      (row.getInt(0),(row.getString(1),row.getInt(2)))}


    val lookupMap = empRdd.collectAsMap()
    def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Int,(String,Int)]) =
         udf((empID:Int) => lookupMap.lift(empID))

    depsDF
      .withColumn("lookup",lookup(lookupMap)($"EmpID"))
      .withColumn("empName",$"lookup._1")
      .withColumn("empAge",$"lookup._2")
      .drop($"lookup")
      .show()
```

Comment: Thanks. In your example, empRdd is not dataframe. How will I convert my dataframe to rdd to use collectAsMap function?

Comment: @Prasan there is an `rdd` method  on the dataframe, so you have to so something like `val empRdd = empDf.rdd.map(row => (row.getInt(0),row.getString(1)))`

Comment: Yeah but collectAsMap is not a member of RDD. When I tried using collect instead of collectAsMap, it gives me an array which I can't use in the lookup function.

Comment: @Prasan if your RDD is of type `RDD[(Int,String)]`, then you should be able to use `collectAsMap` through implicit conversions to `PairRDDFunctions`

Comment: Is there a way to return more than one column instead of only one?  Lets assume you have emp_age as well in your emp dataframe example, Is it possible to display that as well using this look up concept?

Comment: Thanks, it works :) But it crashes when the KEY not found with NoSuchElementException error :(

Comment: @Prasan See my updated answer regarding th Exception (use `lift` on the map). And yes, you could also have multiple "columns", just use a tuple as "value" of your RDD /  map instead of a String

Comment: Thanks "lift" works fine. I tried to return multiple values using list but not sure how do I access it to return. <br/>  val empRdd = empDf.rdd.map(row => (row.getInt(0),List(row.getString(1),row.getString(2)))) <br/> val lookupMap = empRdd.collectAsMap() <br/>
def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Int,Any]) = udf((empID:Int) => lookupMap.lift(empID)) <br/> 
I am not sure how do I access above list in the below .WithColumn statement <br/> .withColumn("empNames",lookup(lookupMap)($"EmpID"))

Comment: @Prasan Use a tuple instead of a List. See my updated answer.

Comment: just wondering what if there are multiple empIds in the look up...is there a way to return all the matched records?

Comment: @Raphael Roth  thanks , is there anyway to do the same without "rdds"

Comment: @Raphael Roth  any clue on how to handle this in map in UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas

Comment: Can anyone convert this line to pyspark .................................................                                                                          def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Int,String]) = udf((empID:Int) => lookupMap.get(empID))

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying you already have Dataframes then its pretty easy follow these steps:

1)create a sqlcontext

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

2) Create Temporary tables for all 3 Eg:

```
EmployeeDataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("EmpTable")
```

3) Query using MySQL Queries

```
val MatchingDetails = sqlContext.sql("SELECT DISTINCT E.EmpID, DeptName FROM EmpTable E inner join DeptTable G on " +
  "E.EmpID=g.EmpID")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned in my post, I don't want to use JOIN.

Comment: why cant you use join when it is serving the purpose

Comment: This is jus an example that I posted. In my real time scenario, we are trying to convert a complex Informatica mapping to SPARK. I am trying to replicate the look up feature (jus like informatica) in SPARK.

Comment: @Prasan Informatica is an old product. When migrating from it, don't try to preserve/replicate "the old ways". `lookup` in spark is very slow, while `join` in its different flavors (inner, outer, left-outer, ...) is very optimized. For the example you used, `join` is the way to go in Spark. If you have other usecase, post it with enough context on a different question.

Comment: I have already implemented using join. But I want to explore using the look up concept as well (jus to learn and see the difference in implementation and performance)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with some "lookup" data, there are two approaches:

Method #1 -- using a lookup DataFrame

```
// use a DataFrame (via a join)
val lookupDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("banana",   "yellow"),
  ("apple",    "red"),
  ("grape",    "purple"),
  ("blueberry","blue")
)).toDF("SomeKeys","SomeValues")
```

Method #2 -- using a map in a UDF

```
// turn the above DataFrame into a map which a UDF uses
val Keys = lookupDF.select("SomeKeys").collect().map(_(0).toString).toList
val Values = lookupDF.select("SomeValues").collect().map(_(0).toString).toList
val KeyValueMap = Keys.zip(Values).toMap

def ThingToColor(key: String): String = {
  if (key == null) return ""
  val firstword = key.split(" ")(0) // fragile!
  val result: String = KeyValueMap.getOrElse(firstword,"not found!")
  return (result)
}

val ThingToColorUDF = udf( ThingToColor(_: String): String )
```

Take a sample data frame of things that will be looked up:

```
val thingsDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("blueberry muffin"),
  ("grape nuts"),
  ("apple pie"),
  ("rutabaga pudding")
)).toDF("SomeThings")
```

**Method #1** is to join on the lookup DataFrame

Here, the **rlike** is doing the matching.  And **null** appears where that does not work.  Both columns of the lookup DataFrame get added.

```
val result_1_DF = thingsDF.join(lookupDF, expr("SomeThings rlike SomeKeys"), 
                     "left_outer")
```

[image: 2 columns are added and nulls where applicable]

**Method #2** is to add a column using the UDF

Here, only 1 column is added.  And the UDF can return a non-Null value.  However, if the lookup data is very large it may fail to "serialize" as required to send to the workers in the cluster.

```
val result_2_DF = thingsDF.withColumn("AddValues",ThingToColorUDF($"SomeThings"))
```

Which gives you:

[image: 1 column is added with values provided by the UDF]

In my case I had some lookup data that was over 1 million values, so Method #1 was my only choice.

Comment: thanks warrens how does this "val KeyValueMap = Keys.zip(Values).toMap" guarantees only "correct" value is mapped to "correct" key?

Comment: any clue on how to handle this in map in UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas