# How to call functions with dataframe operations from spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have sql its basically joining the two table and getting result *accomm_sk*, If the *accomm_sk* value is **NULL** then spark UDF will get call lookup in third table if not then get the result. How can I use this Function in spark sql, as Spark is not allowing to register as UDF?

Spark UDF

```
def GeneratedAccommSk(localHash):
    query = 'select accommodation_sk from staging.accomm_dim where accomm_hash="{}"'.format(localHash)
    accommodationSk_Df=spark.sql(query)
    accomm_count=accommSk_Df.filter(accommSk_Df.accomm_sk.isNotNull()).count()
    if accomm_count != 0:
        accomm_sk=accommSk_Df.select('accomm_sk').collect()[0].asDict()['accomm_sk']
    else:
        func = sc._gateway.jvm.RandomNumberGenerator()
        accom_sk=func.generateRandomNumber().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    return accom_sk
```

Spark SQL:

```
        rate_fact_df=spark.sql("""
*Calling GeneratedAccommSk UDF*
        select  case when accomm_sk IS NOT NULL THEN accommodation_sk 
    ELSE GeneratedAccommSk(a.accommhash) END 
        from 
        staging.contract_test a 
        join 
        dim.accomm_dim b 
        on (a.accomm_hash)= b.accommodation_hash
        """)
```

Comment: why are you not doing using spark data frame instead of sql tables?

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work for at least two reason:

- There is no Py4j gateway on the executors so calling any Java code like this is not an option ([Calling Java/Scala function from a task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684842))
- You cannot use `SparkSession` or any distributed object (`DataFrame`, `RDD`) on the executors ([Why does this Spark code make NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47111607/))

Depending on the size of `accommSk_Df` you should either collect it and use a local object ([Lookup in spark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41275539/)) or perform yet another join.