# Pyspark - Is it possible to use a "Mapping table" to get a desired value based of existing value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering whether it is possible to use another dataframe/table as a mapping table. Here is the best was I can describe it.

dfA (Original dataset)

Below is the original dataset. This is the dataset that we want to change based off a lookup

| Name | TransactionID | Alert flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 93818 | Bad Math |
| Jane Doe | 91982 | Invalid Row |

dfB (Lookup table)

Below is the table which will have references to the alert flag and what each alert flag should equal.

| Alert_flag_OLD | Alert_flag_NEW |
| --- | --- |
| Bad Math | Incorrect Calculations |
| Invalid Row | Invalid Transaction |

What I want to know is. Can we perform a look up. Something like

```
dfA = (
 dfA
 .withColumn('Alert_Flag', LOOKUP on dfB. if (dfA.ALERT_FLAG) in dfB.ALERT_FLAG_OLD then VALUE = ALERT_FLAG_NEW
```

the `if (ALERT_FLAG)` is just saying if the alert flag exists in dfB then use find it's new value.

Is something like this possible?

Have not tried anything as of yet as I wouldn't really know how to start it

Comment: does this responds to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275539/lookup-in-spark-dataframes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first doing `left-join` and then using simple `when-otherwise` construct, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

dfA = spark.createDataFrame([("John Smith", 93818, "Bad Math"), ("Jane Doe", 91982, "Invalid Row")], "Name: string, TransactionID: int, Alert_flag: string")
dfB = spark.createDataFrame([("Bad Math", "Incorrect Calculations"), ("Invalid Row", "Invalid Transaction")], "Alert_flag_OLD: string, Alert_flag_NEW: string")

dfC = dfA.join(dfB, col("Alert_flag") == col("Alert_flag_OLD"), "left")
dfC.withColumn("Alert_flag", when(col("Alert_flag_NEW").isNotNull(), col("Alert_flag_NEW"))).select(["Name", "TransactionID", "Alert_flag"]).show()

+----------+-------------+----------------------+
|Name      |TransactionID|Alert_flag            |
+----------+-------------+----------------------+
|John Smith|93818        |Incorrect Calculations|
|Jane Doe  |91982        |Invalid Transaction   |
+----------+-------------+----------------------+
```